# Acabar un vector de arrays con un while

Tags: c++

Básicamente quiero llenar un vector de strings (he pensado hacerlo con un for), el vector recibirá los datos a través del teclado (con cin). Hasta aquí bien pero no tengo ni idea de cómo hacer para poder parar el ciclo y dejar de rellenar el vector en el momento que yo quiera. Es decir, podría hacer un tamaño máximo no muy amplio y al llegar ahí se acabaría. Pero quiero que sea variable. Había pensado entonces en condicionar el ciclo con un while pero no tengo ni idea de qué es lo que tiene que haber en el while para que funcione. Tengo hecho esto:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

/*
*/
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int tam = 1000;
    string collar[tam];
    cout << "Introduce el nombre de una mazmorra: " ;
    cout << "Cuando termines de introducir datos pulsa 0";

    do{
        for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++)
            cin >> collar[i];
    }while ();

    return 0;
}
```

Pensé en condicionar con el 0, pero me sirve cualquier cosa. Además si alguien cree que todo esto se puede hacer de otra forma mas simple o lo que sea también me gustaría saberlo :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo, no solamente estás cometiendo errores en tu análisis, sino también en la sintaxis. Tal vez esto se solucione si es que nos dispones un poco más de información detallada de lo que quieres llegar.

1. No puedes ingresar un **string** vía **cin>>**. Es necesario que utilices la función **getline(inputStream, string)**. EJEMPLO: **getline(cin, collar[i])**
2. Para guardar caracteres, es mejor utilizar un array de **char**. La diferencia entre **char** y **string** es que el primer tipo solamente almacena 1 byte (Eso significa que si tú ingresas "ROJO" solamente se guarda el primer caracter) y el segundo tipo es un puntero dinámico de **char** (Eso significa que si tú ingresas "ROJO" se guarda todos los caracteres de la palabra).

Corregí un poco el código sin hacerlo inentendible para tu visión.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string collar[100];
    cout << "Introduce el nombre de una mazmorra: " ;
    cout << "Cuando termines de introducir datos pulsa 0";

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        getline(cin, collar[i]);
        if(collar[i]=="0")
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

El **break** colocado al final acaba con el **for** antes de que se cumpla la condición de acabar con todos los elementos.

Comment: Si se puede leer un `std::string` vía `cin >>`. Otra cosa es que no sea recomendable.

Comment: Si lees un std::string via cin>> solamente ingresará todo lo anterior al space (' '). Si ingresas "Hola mundo", solo se leerá "Hola".

Comment: Justamente por eso es que no es recomendable usar `cin >>` para leer  un `std::string`. Puedes tranquilamente leer nombres por ejemplo, pero si intentas leer nombres y apellidos pasará lo que mencionas. Mi punto es que no es lo mismo *no se puede* con *debería evitarse porque sucede esto o aquello*.

Answer (score 0):

Para que el vector de strings sea de tamaño variable debes crearlo de forma dinámica. Aca te envio un codigo similar a lo que necesitas, le añadí algunos comentarios, de todas formas si no entiendes algo puedes preguntar.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int size = 3;
int count = 0;
string * collar = new string[size];
string reciever;
string * temporal;

cout<< "Intoduce el nombre de una mazmorra: ";
cout<< "Pulsa 0 para terminar de introducir datos.";

while (true)
{
    fflush(stdin); //Limpiar el buffer de entrada
    cin>>reciever;   //Almacenas el valor entrado en una variable temporal para verificar si es cero o un dato válido.
    if(reciever.compare("0")==0) //En caso de ser cero terminas el ciclo while.
        break;
    else   //Si no lo almacenas en tu vector.
    {
        if(count==size) // Aumentar el tamaño del vector ya que ha alcanzado su capacidad máxima.
        {
            temporal = new string[size+10];
            for (int j=0;j<size;j++)
            {
                temporal[j]=collar[j];
            }
            delete[] collar;
            collar = temporal;
        }            
        collar[count]=reciever;   
        count++;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

De esta forma puedes ingresar tantos strings como necesites y usarlos a conveniencia teniendo en cuenta que se almacenan en collar[...] cada posicion contiene un string.

Comment: Es bien conocido que `fflush(stdin)` produce comportamiento indefinido.